# Matlab integration of circle circumference

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

It could be a simple question. I am trying to understand numerical integration in Matlab. For a unit circle,

```
fun = @(x) sqrt(cosd(x).^2+sind(x).^2);
q = integral(fun,0,360);
```

The answer is `360.0000`, whereas I expect it to be `2*pi`. Note that the angle is maintained is degrees. I am confused. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `cosd` and `sind` which use *degrees* and you're specifying your limits in *degrees*, so the output is going to be degrees as well. Remember that `2*pi` radians *is* 360 degrees.

If you want radians, you'll want to use `cos` and `sin` instead of `cosd` and `sind`, and use `0` and `2*pi` for your limits.

```
fun = @(x)sqrt(cos(x).^2 + sin(x).^2);
q = integral(fun, 0, 2*pi);
```

Comment: Thanks. Due to negative votes, I will delete the question

Comment: @SathishKrishnan I wouldn't do that. Since it has an answer leave it here otherwise it contributes to a question ban.